# how to add empty or NA row when condition is met

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fp15wqa7AvZHNHai1ENC16OWV5RW9KdEdrZDdJdnpHNHJj/view?usp=sharing). In column `CYC` I have a sequence belonging to the `ID` column. When the name in the `ID` column changes then the sequence in the `CYC` column starts with `1`. My question is: When the sequence starts with `2`, How do I insert a row with `NA's` above the `2`? this solution should be robust enough to handle inserting two `NA` rows if the sequence starts with `3` or `3 NA` rows if the sequence starts with `4` and so on. Would it be possible to add the name of the sample from the `ID` column to the inserted `NA` rows to fill up the start of the sequence in the `CYC` column?
An example of the expected result of the `CYC` column is this:

```
   CYC
1   NA
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10  10
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  15
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: `@CDoug` I just added an expected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
library('tidyverse')

df <- tribble(
       ~ID, ~CYC, ~COUNTS,
    'WSTD',    1,       1,
    'WSTD',    2,       2,
      'S1',    2,       3,
      'S1',    3,       4,
      'S1',    4,       5,
  'THB381',    3,       6
)
```

We want to get a data frame with all the required combinations of ID and CYC. We can do this with list columns and `unnest`.

```
cycs <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(CYC = list(seq_len(max(CYC)))) %>%
  unnest
```

Then just `right_join` it to the original data frame and the missing rows will be filled with `NA`s.

```
right_join(df, cycs)
#> Joining, by = c("ID", "CYC")
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>       ID   CYC COUNTS
#>    <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     S1     1     NA
#> 2     S1     2      3
#> 3     S1     3      4
#> 4     S1     4      5
#> 5 THB381     1     NA
#> 6 THB381     2     NA
#> 7 THB381     3      6
#> 8   WSTD     1      1
#> 9   WSTD     2      2
```

Comment: `@Paul` when I copy script then I get this message: `Error in UseMethod("right_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'right_join' applied to an object of class "function"` and also what does `df <- tribble (...` do?

Comment: It works for me in a new session. I think it is trying to use the df function rather than the data frame. Did you create the df object?

Comment: `@Paul` I did this: `data <- read.csv("needed_columns.csv")` and replaced `df` in your example with `data`.

Comment: `@Paul` thanks, now I only get the error: `Joining, by = c("ID", "CYC")` in the console and when I write a csv of `right_joinn` then only a `x` appears in it.

Answer (score 1):

To keep this self-contained we use the data `DF` in the Note at the end consisting of the `THB381` rows.

We use `by` to process each `ID` separately generating a data frame with the `ID` and `CYC` from 1 to the last `CYC` for that `ID`.  Then `rbind` the data frames so produced together.  Finally we merge that with the original data frame.  No  packages are used.

```
merge(DF, 
      do.call("rbind", by(DF, DF$ID, with, data.frame(ID = ID[1], CYC = 1:tail(CYC, 1)))), 
      all = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
       ID CYC POS COUNTS2 CTIME_mins
1  THB381   1  NA      NA         NA
2  THB381   2  40     206   100.0297
3  THB381   3  40     212   100.0297
4  THB381   4  40     204   100.0296
5  THB381   5  40     186   100.0297
6  THB381   6  40     177   100.0297
7  THB381   7  40     195   100.0297
8  THB381   8  40     189   100.0130
9  THB381   9  40     195   100.0297
10 THB381  10  40     184   100.0297
11 THB381  11  40     209   100.0296
12 THB381  12  40     194   100.0297
13 THB381  13  40     197   100.0297
14 THB381  14  40     194   100.0297
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "S1", "S2", 
"TCB995", "THB379", "THB380", "THB381", "THB382", "THB383", "THB384", 
"THB385", "THB386", "THB387", "THB388", "TPB166", "TPN270", "WSTD"
), class = "factor"), POS = c(40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), CYC = 2:14, COUNTS2 = c(206L, 
212L, 204L, 186L, 177L, 195L, 189L, 195L, 184L, 209L, 194L, 197L, 
194L), CTIME_mins = c(100.02965, 100.02965, 100.02955, 100.02965, 
100.02965, 100.02965, 100.012983333333, 100.02965, 100.02965, 
100.02955, 100.02965, 100.02965, 100.02965)), .Names = c("ID", 
"POS", "CYC", "COUNTS2", "CTIME_mins"), row.names = 256:268, class = "data.frame")
```